# How to specify crashkernel in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

I configured kdump-tools according to 
https://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/linux/312-installing-and-configuring-kdump-on-debian-jessie. But my kernel doesn't see **crashkernel** in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.

My kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pavel-test-106 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I updated /etc/default/grub:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0,38400n8 elevator=noop"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=True
GRUB_GFXMODE="auto"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=True
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
TERMINAL="console"
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="crashkernel=128M cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

then

```
$ update-grub
$ reboot now
```

And there is no effect:

```
$ kdump-config show
[FAIL] no crashkernel= parameter in the kernel cmdline ... failed!
USE_KDUMP:        1
KDUMP_SYSCTL:     kernel.panic_on_oops=1
KDUMP_COREDIR:    /var/crash
crashkernel addr: 
current state:    Not ready to kdump

kernel link: 


kexec command:
  no kexec command recorded
```

Kernel cmdline:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=328c1eeb-1a6f-4fa6-a850-b59782541c5c ro console=ttyS0,38400n8 elevator=noop cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1
```